# Каково происхождение слов «сахар» и «Саха́ра»?

Tags: этимология

Высохшая местность — Сахара (пустыня в Африке); осушенный до кристаллического состояния сироп — сахар (бытовое название сахарозы); подсохший хлеб — сухарь.

Возможно ли, чтобы слова *Сахара, сахар* и *сухарь* произошли от одного и того же корня, например «сух»?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, невозможно. Сахар и Сахара - да, однокоренные.
"Са́хар" заимствовано в древнерусский период из греческого, в котором sakcharon восходит к палийскому sakkhara — «песок». В словаре Л. Успенского читаем:

> Мы говорим «сахар» про кусковой, твердый сахар и называем «сахарным песком» сахар раздробленный, размельченный. Но само это слово родилось из индийского «sakhara», а оно значило именно «гравий, песок» (и в частности, «песок сахарный»). Через греческое «сакхарон» оно проникло во все европейские языки: «сюкр» (французское), «цу́ккер» (немецкое), «шуга» (английское). Говоря «сахарный песок», мы, собственно, говорим «песчаный песок».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80

А вот "сухарь" - от "сухой".  Н. Шанский утверждает:

> СУХОЙ. Общеслав., имеющее соответствия в др. индоевроп. яз. Корень тот
>   же, что в сохнуть. Исходно — «вялый, увядший».

Фасмер согласен:

> сухо́й сух, суха́, су́хо, укр. сухи́й, блр. сухí, др.-русск. сухъ, ст.-слав. соухъ ξηρός (Супр.), болг. сух, сербохорв. су̯х, ж. су́ха, словен. sȗh, súha, слвц., чеш. suchý, польск. suchy, в.-луж. suchi, н.-луж. suchy, полаб. sä́uche Праслав. *suхъ родственно лит. saũsas «сухой», лтш. sàuss, др.-прусск. sausai нареч., греч. αὖος «сухой», англос. séar «сухой, увядший», ср.-нж.-нем. sôr «сухой», др.-инд. c̨оṣаs м. «сухость», c̨ōṣas «иссушающий», алб. thanj «сушу» (*sausni̯ō; см. Г. Майер, Alb. Wb. 88), с др. ступенью вокализма — со́хнуть (см.), др.-инд. c̨úṣkas, c̨uṣkás «сухой», авест. huška-, др.-инд. c̨úṣyati «сохнет, вянет».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%81/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9

Так что сахар и сухарь имеют разные корни, к тому же один из греческого языка, другой - общеславянский.

Comment: С сахаром и Сахарой не так просто: Sahara

1610s, from Arabic çahra "desert" (plural çahara), according to Klein, noun use of fem. of the adjective asharu "yellowish red." Related: Saharan.

  Поскольку связь арабского с индо-европейскими современной наукой не установлена, об одинаковых корнях здесь говорить нет оснований.

Comment: Первоисточник не арабский, а палийский. Па́ли — пракрит одного из среднеиндийских языков индийской (или индоарийской) группы индоевропейской семьи языков. К арабам слово пришло тоже из Индии. Сахар - песок и Сахара - песок, так что корень один.

Comment: Вот о том, что слово ṣaḥra (صحرا /ˈsˤaħra/), пришло к арабам из Индии, никаких подтверждений найти не удаётся. Если у вас они есть, поделитесь. Может оно так и есть, но почему-то об этом везде молчок. А совпадения в языках обычное дело.

Comment: Слово «сахар» во многих языках звучит как «сухарь».  Например: siùcair (шотл.), sukero (эсп.), socker (шв.), cukr (чеш.), cukier (поль.), sukker (норв.), zucchero (ит.), cukor (венг.)…
Забавно, что при переводе слова «сахар» на португальский, польский, итальянский, испанский и пр., - Яндекс.Переводчик подсказывает еще и перевод слова «Сахара» будто намекая, что это синонимы.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это разные слова. СахарА - пустыня в арабском, сахар пришёл к нам через персов (шякар) из санскрита (шаркара), а сухарь и сухой вообще про своё.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очевиден - **да, это одно слово**. Здесь сложность только со словом "**Сахара**" поскольку в нашем представлении - это много песка; что не совсем так, поскольку песка в Сахаре 15% от всей площади. Однако представьте себя путником идущим по этой пустыне. Пластиковых контейнеров у вас нет, а есть в лучшем случае холщовый  **мешок с хлебом** и чем-то там ещё. Понятно, что ваши продукты очень быстро высохнут, а **хлеб** превратится в **твёрдый сухарь**. Кроме того местные **туареги** издавна путешествуют по пустыне обязательно с *зелёным чаем*, который пьют с **сахаром**, заваривая чай так, чтобы взбить пену. Такой чай очень сильно *бодрит* и действует как допинг. При пересечении пустыни требуются высококалорийные продукты, а сахар и сухари - самые простые из них. Таким образом слово **Сахара** содержит в себе понятия ***"и сахар и сухарь и сухость".***

**Сахар**. В русском языке очень твёрдо закреплено, что сахар - это *кусковой продукт*. Для того, чтобы попросить , чтобы вам дали сахарный песок, нужно говорить "*дайте мне песку*", тогда как для того, чтобы попросить кусковой сахар нужно сказать "*дайте мне сахар*". Это говорит о том, что слово **сахар** означает нечто **твёрдое**. Да и *производство сахара* исторически - это получение прежде всего *твёрдого продукта*. По своим свойствам *твёрдый сахар*, чем-то напоминает *твёрдый сухарь*: и сахар и сухарь получаются из первоначально мягкой массы( для сухаря - это тесто и хлеб), и сахар и сухарь - колятся и крошатся, и сахар и сухарь - продукты питания с высокой питательностью, и сахар и сухарь можно и лучше всего размачивать. Кроме того, тот **сахар**, что получали изначально был **жёлтого цвета**, что делало похожим кусок сахара на кусок обожжённого сухаря из белого хлеба. Далее жёлтый сахар и сухарь по цвету похожи на **песок**. Следовательно слово **сахар**  подразумевает ***"такое же твёрдое и способное колоться и крошиться как сухарь"***, как и прочие смыслы.

Дополнительно, название пустыни Сахары - "**Саха́ра**" - это *родительный падеж* от слова "сахар": нет кого? чего? - "**са́хара**". Отсюда выражение "**пустыня Сахара**" означает буквально следующее: место, где из сахара(тверди) образуется сухой песок, - в полном соответствии с русской традицией называть сахаром твёрдый или кусковой  сахар, а песком - сахар-песок. Именно поэтому на уровне языка выражение "пустыня Сахара" воспринимается как местность, где много песка.

Таким образом имеем связку из трёх слов на основе понятия "сухой":

**Сухарь → сахар → Сахара.**